# XSLT report not getting updated after multiple runs

Tags: xml, xslt, ant, testng

XSLT report not getting updated after multiple runs. However, TestNG report is getting updated after every run. Please, assist what might be the reason??

Below is the build.xml file. Please, let me know for more details.

```
<!-- Create class path for jar files -->
<path id="jarfiles">
    <!-- .class files location -->
    <pathelement location="${basedir}/bin" />
    <!-- jar files location -->
    <fileset dir="${basedir}/lib">
        <!-- include .jar files -->
        <include name="*.jar" />
    </fileset>
</path>
<target name="clean">
    <!-- delete bin folder in project -->
    <delete dir="${basedir}/bin" />
</target>
<!-- Create target compile , name can be anything -->
<target name="compile">
    <!-- delete bin folder in project -->
    <delete dir="${basedir}/bin" />
    <!-- create bin folder in project -->
    <mkdir dir="${basedir}/bin" />

    <!-- compile .java files to .class file , files will be stored in bin folder -->
    <javac srcdir="${basedir}/src" destdir="${basedir}/bin" classpathref="jarfiles"  includeantruntime="false"/>

</target>
<!-- close target -->
<!-- create class path testing file -->
<taskdef name="Rupa" classname="org.testng.TestNGAntTask">
    <classpath>
        <!-- locate testing jar file -->
        <pathelement location="${basedir}/lib/testng-6.9.9.jar" />
    </classpath>
</taskdef>
<!-- run target starts, depends on compile -->

<target name="run">
    <!-- create reports folder in project -->
    <mkdir dir="${basedir}/Results" />
    <Rupa outputdir="${basedir}/Results" classpathref="jarfiles">
        <!-- execute testng.xml file -->
        <xmlfileset dir="${basedir}/src/com/test/in" includes="testng.xml">
        </xmlfileset>
    </Rupa>
</target>
<target name="xsltreports">
    <delete dir="${basedir}/XSLT_Reports/output"/>
    <mkdir dir="${basedir}/XSLT_Reports/output" />

    <xslt in="${basedir}/test-output/testng-results.xml" style="${basedir}/testng-results.xsl" out="${basedir}/XSLT_Reports/output/index.html" classpathref="jarfiles" processor="SaxonLiaison">

        <param name="testNgXslt.outputDir" expression="${basedir}/XSLT_Reports/output/" />
        <param name="testNgXslt.showRuntimeTotals" expression="true" />
    </xslt>
</target>
```

Comment: How are running the build? Have you tried "ant run xsltreports"?

Comment: yes i used ant run xslt report

Comment: I notice you're deleting the output directory at the start of the "xsltreports" target.... If you're confident that the target is running then surely an output is being created? In your question you're saying it's not being updated.... No longer makes sense.

Comment: for the first time report is generated. But if i run it once again it gives me the same report.no change.

Comment: that is why i am deleting the old report and trying to get new report.